# Apache: 500 Error after Successful User Authentication?

Tags: python, django, apache, authentication, mod-wsgi

I am currently working on a site that is deployed on an AWS EC2 instance using Apache, Django, and mod_wsgi. I am trying to configure my Apache to use mod_authz_user and a python script for user validation following [this tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/apache-auth/) but after implementing it, I get a 500 error when successfully logging into the server and the error logs show nothing except that there was an initial GET request for the home page of the site. The structure of my code follows the tutorial linked above pretty much to tea, so I'm not sure what could be going wrong. The site properly asks the user for the username and password, and I know for sure my authentication script is being called by Apache.

Technically, all I need is the HTTP_AUTHENTICATION head to be set for my Django application, so if I could somehow have the user enter in their credentials but not have Apache validate it (which leads to the 500 error) that would be great. In that case the HTTP_AUTHENTICATION header would be set because the user entered in the credentials and then my Django application could deal with the authentication from there.

For a bit more context, this site runs on an intranet and I am attempting to make it so that not just anybody can access the site internally in the company. Once the Windows user is passed into Django I will check the membership of the user against an AD group.

Comment: I think your application is not running can you check if you Django is running normally. Follow this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-16-04 Maybe this can help

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, I'm sure my application is running because everything works perfectly as long as I'm not including the authentication piece on the Apache side. If I just use Require all granted for each section of the configuration file, every works great.